# expression must have a constant value

Tags: c++, arrays, input

I am trying to create an array out of a string input.

```
string input;
getline(cin,input);
string inputarray1[100];
istringstream pp(input);
int* inputPosition=0;
while (!pp.eof())
{
    getline( pp, inputarray1[*inputPosition], ' ' );
    inputPosition++;
}
int* a = inputPosition;
string halp[a];
```

I am using getline to parse my input (along with an istringstream) and placing that into an array, but how can I create an array that has no extra empty locations?

Comment: I think you need to do more to tell us about what you're trying to accomplish, and less about how you've tried to accomplish it.

Comment: How about using vector<string> instead of an array?

Comment: Why are you using an int pointer as an int?

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question? (FWIW, it looks like you just want to do `std::vector<std::string> input(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<std::string>());`).

Comment: the title was the error i get highlighting the a in halp[a]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a vector, from the header `<vector>`

```
vector<string> inputArray;
while (getline(pp, input, ' '))
    inputArray.push_back(input);
```

The number of strings can be obtained with `inputArray.size()`, and you can access individual elements just like with an array, `inputArray[index]`.

Note that `operator>>` is delimited on whitespace, so you can probably also do this(unless you for some reason want to treat tabs differently)

```
while (pp >> input)
    inputArray.push_back(input);
```

Comment: that worked, but now

try {
if (atoi(inputarrayconverted[p].c_str()) >= 0)
    {
    inputarrayconverted[p] = "n";
    }
}
catch (int e) { }

is not working. it is giving me a "Debug Assertion Failed!" message. All I'm trying to do is verify that if the array position is an int, change the other array's respective value to 'n'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on your question, but it sounds like you really want to use a [Hash Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) instead of an array. This will let you map user inputs to something else, without the empty array locations you mentioned.

Comment: i suppose i'm mostly asking how to create a counter within the while loop, and use that final number to create a new array of the same size, to then map the inputarray1[] to halp[].

All of the websites that have solutions to these problems say "create a large array, store your values, then create another array of a smaller size." i guess i'm just confused on how to create an array of the proper size.

Comment: Then you can use something like a vector. See Benjamin Lindley's answer.